# Problem saving file using fs with no errors

Tags: node.js, file, discord.js, node.js-fs

for some reason theres a problem with this: `js let jsonString = JSON.stringify(config, null, 2); fs.writeFileSync("commands/ai/config.json", jsonString, "utf-8");` its not saving to the file.

i have other files using the same code and they are working just fine. this one file isnt working though and its in the same directory.

i tried directly copying the code from one file to another and it didnt help. it might be a problem that i cant see or maybe im just making a stupid mistake

Comment: Do you realize that this code is using a relative path that will evaluated from the current working directory, not from the module directory?  Are you sure this file is going where you want it to?  Also, with the synchronous version, you would catch errors with `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the relative path of your code. The best way it's to use `path.join(__dirname, "commands/ai/config.json")`.
With this you can log `__dirname` and check that the path is correct.
(Check the doc https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname)